# How to do data-parallel image processing?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a simple data-parallel image process filter in Rust.
I've got it working in single thread with the following code.

```
/// an example of a very simple filter
fn modular_filter_chunk(input: &[u16], slice_width: usize, slice_height: usize, mod_value: u16, output: &mut[u16]) {
    let size = slice_width*slice_height;
    for i in 0..size {
        output[i] = input[i] % mod_value;
    }
}

fn modular_filter_multi(input: &Vec<u16>, width: usize, height: usize, slice_num: usize, mod_value: u16, output: &mut Vec<u16>) {
    // divide image vertically to slices
    let height_per_slice = height / slice_num;
    let size_per_chunk = height_per_slice * width;
    let in_itr = input.chunks(size_per_chunk);
    let out_itr = output.chunks_mut(size_per_chunk);
    for (input, output) in in_itr.zip(out_itr) {
        modular_filter_chunk(input, width, height_per_slice, mod_value, output);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let width: usize = 1024;
    let height: usize = 1024;
    let input = vec![1234; width*height];
    let mut output = vec![0; width*height];
    modular_filter_multi(&input, width, height, 4, 73, &mut output);
}
```

Now I want to process the for loop in parallel, but I can't figure out a simple way to do this. I tried changing the for loop like the following but can't get through the compile error.

```
let mut handles = Vec::new();
for (input, output) in in_itr.zip(out_itr) {
    let h = std::thread::spawn(move || {
        modular_filter_chunk(input, width, height_per_slice, mod_value, output);
    });
    handles.push(h);
}
for handle in handles {
    handle.join().unwrap();
}
```

### Compile error message

```
src\main.rs:25:21: 25:43 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter 'a in function call due to c
onflicting requirements
src\main.rs:25  let in_itr = input.chunks(size_per_chunk);
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src\main.rs:27:25: 27:44 note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the method call at 27:24...
src\main.rs:27  for (input, output) in in_itr.zip(out_itr) {
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src\main.rs:27:2: 29:3 note: expansion site
src\main.rs:27:25: 27:31 note: ...so that method receiver is valid for the method call
src\main.rs:27  for (input, output) in in_itr.zip(out_itr) {
                                       ^~~~~~
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src\main.rs:27:2: 29:3 note: expansion site
src\main.rs:25:15: 25:20 note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the expression at 25:14...
src\main.rs:25  let in_itr = input.chunks(size_per_chunk);
                             ^~~~~
src\main.rs:25:15: 25:20 note: ...so that pointer is not dereferenced outside its lifetime
src\main.rs:25  let in_itr = input.chunks(size_per_chunk);
                             ^~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `rust_multithread`.
```

How should I change my code to get the filter working in parallel?

Comment: Please create a [MCVE](/help/mcve). I'd be willing to bet that a much smaller example would reproduce the same problem. Have you looked at any of the other questions here that have the same error message? How does this differ from those? Have you tried doing what the error message tells you? As it is right now, your question doesn't show much effort towards solving your own problem.

Comment: @rillomas Yeas, you should make it much smaller, this way it make it much easier to spot the issue, here is a minimal version of your code for example: http://is.gd/JfulvR which I think reproduce your issue. If it is indeed the case, editing your question with it would certainly help to make it more easily answerable.

Comment: OK I updated the example to a smaller one. I'll see if I can solve this by myself but I'll keep the question posted to see if anyone can give me help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got it working with the following steps.

1. Install Rust Nightly.
2. Add `#![feature(scoped)]` to the top of the source code.
3. Use the following code as a replacement for the `modular_filter_chunk` for loop.

   ```
   let mut handles = Vec::new();
   for (input, output) in in_itr.zip(out_itr) {
       let h = std::thread::scoped(move || {
           modular_filter_chunk(input, width, height_per_slice, mod_value, output);
       });
       handles.push(h);
   }
   for handle in handles {
       handle.join();
   }
   ```

I initially thought `thread::scoped` might be a solution, but since it was unstable I couldn't get it to compile. I wonder if there is a way to solve this without using `thread::scoped` or `unsafe`.

Comment: You can avoid using `scoped` by keeping all data (the real owners, not just borrowed pointers) in a struct inside an `Arc` object, so that static lifetime requirement of `thread::spawn` could be satisfied.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that too, but I believe using `Arc` and `Mutex` will only allow a single thread to process the image at one time. What I wanted was simultaneous processing (parallel processing) from multiple threads, so I couldn't use `Arc` and `Mutex`.

Comment: You don't need a mutex :) Mutex is to prevent simultaneous access, while you need exactly the opposite - to process the same vector with multiple threads simultaneously.

Comment: I think you can share the input without a `Mutex` (because it doesn't get mutated), but don't you need a`Mutex` for the output? I thought Rust prohibits sharing mutable data.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the signature for [`thread::spawn`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html):

```
pub fn spawn<F, T>(f: F) -> JoinHandle<T>
    where F: FnOnce() -> T,
          F: Send + 'static,
          T: Send + 'static
```

This states that `spawn` takes a type `F` that implements `FnOnce` (will be called exactly once) and when called will return something of type `T`. The types `F` and `T` must implement `Send` and must have at least the lifetime `'static`.

The [`Send`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Send.html) bound restricts the possible types to "types able to be transferred across thread boundaries" and `'static` means that any references in the type must live for the *entire* lifetime of the program, from before `main` starts to after `main` exits.

This explains the error message you are getting: none of your references are guaranteed to live for the entire life of the program. In fact, they are guaranteed to **not** live that long.

When you `spawn` a thread, the new thread no longer has any concrete connection to the thread that spawned it. It is more than possible that the new thread will outlive the parent! This would cause Very Bad Things to happen if you tried to use the reference after the parent thread died.

As you found, `thread::scoped` provides a solution to this. Scoped threads are required to be joined before any of the references they contain expire. **However**, scoped threads are unstable for a reason: they are [unsound in the presence of reference cycles](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24292). There was a [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1084) to bring it back, but there's some deep details around it, so it's been deferred.

As [hamstergene points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216262/how-to-do-data-parallel-image-processing#comment50442802_31221024), you can use [`Arc`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) to safely share immutable data in stable Rust. You would need to use [`Mutex`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) to share your mutable output buffer though. You can tell why people are excited to have `thread::scoped` reinstated!

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the background! I also saw that issue related to scoped threads before, and since it seemed to take some time to resolve I was looking for a method that doesn't use scoped threads. Maybe I'll have a look at a more full fledged fork-join library.